# How to set emacs to open new files in current instance on Ubuntu/Mint?

Tags: emacs, ubuntu

I want to keep emacs open most of the time, and then whenever I open a text file, python file, etc (from nautilus/finder), I want it to open as a new buffer in my current emacs instance, rather than starting a new instance.

I tried following this [guide](http://anxiousmofo.wordpress.com/2008/08/04/opening-files-in-an-already-running-instance-of-emacs/):

I wasn't really sure about what to do with the file, but what I tried was copying it to /usr/bin/emacs_openfile, adding #!/bin/sh to the first line, and running chmod +x emacs_openfile

However, it doesn't work for me and just opens a new instance, even though I was able to associate text files with this program.

On a sidenote, I set emacs as the default editor using [this](https://superuser.com/questions/168702/how-do-i-change-the-default-text-editor-in-ubuntu).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Bad-ptr/e05fb8d02436214abd89

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want [emacs client](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient).

Basically, set `emacsclient` as your default editor, and add `(server-start)` somewere in your emacs config.

There needs to be a running Emacs instance for `emacsclient` to work, but if it's a hassle it's possible to have a [headless Emacs launched at login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458419/how-to-keep-a-persistent-emacs-server-instance-running).

Comment: How could I have a headless emacs launched at login?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458419/how-to-keep-a-persistent-emacs-server-instance-running

Comment: Exactly :) I added that link to my answer.

Comment: A function I keep in my *.bashrc* is `e() { nohup emacsclient --alternate-editor="emacs" "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1 & }` which lets you "throw" files at emacs from a terminal without activating any foreground processes by issuing `e file`.

Comment: I have no problem with starting emacs. But one thing that disturbs me is the fact, that when I open a file with `emacsclient` as external editor the emacsclient window always always and shows me its messages first and it will popup multiple times. So i traded the multiple emacs isntances with multiple emacsclient instance windows :/

Answer (score 3):

Did you start server in emacs?  Make sure that you add `(server-start)` to your .emacs or do `M-x server-start` from an existing EMACS session.

Conceptually, it's really easy, just do `emacsclient` *file-name* on the command line or where you name the program.

Answer (score 1):

Just for your information, If you are using GUI version on Mac, the dir os `emacsclient` is below:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient
```