# How to keep a persistent emacs-server instance running?

Tags: emacs, ubuntu

I use emacs-server so that I can set emacsclient as the default texteditor and have it open up new files as buffers rather than new emacs instances.

However, this only works when emacs server is running, so how can I have this run at startup and stay in the background?

Another issue is that if i start emacs, then quit it and restart it, it tells me:

File error: Cannot bind server socket, address already in use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using Emacs 23, put

```
emacs --daemon
```

in your `~/.xsession` (or wherever you place your startup commands).

Comment: cheers for that. i added emacs --daemon to the startup applications app, which seemed to work as when I started up emacs it gave me File error: Cannot bind server socket, address already in use. Though how can I fix that error? I tried emacsclient from the cli, I got - emacsclient: connect: Connection refused
emacsclient: No socket or alternate editor.  Please use:

 --socket-name
 --server-file      (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE)
 --alternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)

Comment: Do you still have `(server-start)` in your `~/.emacs`?  Try to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient) page should tell you all you need to know. An alternative to the suggestion igor made is to make a new script somewhere on you path that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1
exec emacsclient --alternate-editor="" -c "$@"
```

Assuming you are using GTK.

The alternate-editor="" is a shorthand that tells emacs to start a new server if none is found. This is all from the EmacsWiki page. There are also some fixes for the Connection refused error posted. You should always start there when trying to figure out something about emacs.